# NoReverseMatch at /polls/2/

Tags: python-3.x, django

**Django version:** *3.0.8*

**Python version:** *3.8.0*

I'm doing a Django tutorial and I ran into this error below

[image]

"detail.html" below

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}
<h1>{{question.question_text}}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action ="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
     <input type="radio" name = "choice" id="choice{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{choice.id}}"/>
     <label for="choice{{forloop.counter}}">{{choice.choice_text}}</label><br>
   {% endfor %}

<input type="submit" value="vote"/>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

"base.html" below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Base</title>
</head>
<body>

<hr>
<p> Header </p>
<hr>
{% block main_content %}
{% endblock %}
{% include "polls/footer.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help with this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please also add the code of `footer.html`

Comment: show us your urls.py

Comment: 'from django.conf.urls import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = \
    [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail"),
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$', views.results, name="results"),
        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/votes$', views.votes, name="votes"),
    ]
app_name = 'polls' '

Comment: <hr>
<p>Footer</p>
<hr>

Comment: its a typo, your route reverse name=votes not vote you should edit your template accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in `urls.py` you shared in comment. Please replace last url name from `votes` to `vote`. Hopefully It will resolve this error. Please test and share your results. Thanks

**Solution Code:**

```
from django.conf.urls import * 
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"), 
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name="detail"),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results$', views.results, name="results"),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote$', views.votes, name="vote"), 
] 
app_name = 'polls'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `polls/footer.html`, uses `{% url 'vote' ... %}` somewhere instead of `{% url 'polls:vote' ... %}`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to register a vote path in `urls.py` like `path('<int:pk>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),` you also need a view handler in `views.py` it's the one being used as `views.vote`